# I am new to python programming and I have an assignment in which I have to print a certain pattern of stars using a function

Tags: python

The pattern is given below. The number of rows is to be specified by the user. In this image it is 6. I know how to print the upper half but I am finding difficulty in the lower half. Please help.

[image]
I tried this code:

```
def asterisk_triangle(n):
x = 1
while (x <= n):
    print("*" * x)
    x = x + 1
return
```

Comment: What did you try and how did it failed?

Comment: `print('\n'.join('*'*int(i) for i in str(pow(int('1'*5),2))))` <--  easiest way

Comment: If you're going to answer the question, post an answer; don't post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have top half done, the bottom is similar, but reversed (rather than printing a number of stars equal to the row number, print a number of starts equal to the **total number of rows** minus the current row number).  For example:

```
num = raw_input("Please enter number: ")
for i in range(num):
   print "*" * i
```

then the opposite would be:

```
for j in range(num):
    print "*" * (num-i)
```

Comment: the number of rows is to be specified by the user.

Comment: @Heisenberg, edited for input.  Also, I'm using 2, looks like you're using 3, so `print` uses parenthesis for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def pattern(lines):
 for i in range(0, lines / 2):
      print "*" * i
 for i in range(lines / 2, 0, -1):
      print "*" * i
```